# Is there a subsetting function in R that allows me to balance subsets with conditions?

Tags: r, subset

I'm dealing with a large dataset that needs to be subset to run on multiple threads at the same time.  In order to do that, I need to break it into N subsets, with the subsets being hopefully about the same size.  However, I have a category variable within the table, and I need to make sure that everything with the same category is in the same subset.  Some categories only have 2 rows, but some may have up to 2,000 rows. The higher priority is that no category goes across more than one subset, so if I have a dataset with 5,000 rows, and 3,000 are within one category, and I'm splitting into three subsets, I'd have one of that 3,000, and then two more of approximately 1,000.

I'm thinking of using the table() command to preload frequencies of each of the categories, but I'm a bit stymied on figuring out how to do the subsetting automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach comes to mind using `data.table`, and is a bit analogous to your plan to use `table` but hopefully makes it a bit more automatic and general.

The approach is to basically look at counts within each `category`, calculate cumulative counts over all categories, and `cut` the cumulative sum values into `nSubsets` (approximately) equal sized groups:

```
library(data.table)

## dummy up some data;
dt <- data.table(category = rep(1:256, sample(2:2000, 256, replace = T)))
## view couts by category;
dt[, .N, by = category]

# how many subsets do you want?;
nSubsets <- 4

## here we will assign each category value to a subset;
dt[, .(.N),
   by = .(category)][order(N), .(category,
                         subset = cut(cumsum(N), breaks = nSubsets))]

## join above to your data;
dt[dt[, .(.N),
      by = .(category)][order(N), .(category,
                            subset = cut(cumsum(N), breaks = nSubsets))],
   subset := i.subset,
   on = "category"]


dt
dt[, .N, by = subset]
```

Now, your data will have a column named `subset` which will not vary within categories, but cuts your data into nearly equally sized subsets.

Comment: That looks excellent! I'm gonna give it a try tonight when my current process finishes. Thanks so much!

Comment: I meant to write earlier, but this worked perfectly!

Comment: Glad it worked for you. I'm not sure how robust it would be for severely unbalanced categories, but I think including the `order(N)` while creating the `subset` field should help with that.